# How to access Marshalling iOS [Nativescript]

Tags: plugins, nativescript

I currently have a functional plugin, but I have a problem being able to get the object in the finishCheckout method

```js
import { Options } from "./mercadopago-px.common";
import * as frameModule from "tns-core-modules/ui/frame";

export class LifeCycleProtocolImpl extends NSObject
    implements PXLifeCycleProtocol {
    public resolve: any;
    public reject: any;

    static ObjCProtocols = [PXLifeCycleProtocol]; // define our native protocalls

    static new(): LifeCycleProtocolImpl {
        return <LifeCycleProtocolImpl>super.new(); // calls new() on the NSObject
    }

    cancelCheckout(): () => void {
        this.reject({
            status: "cancel",
            data: null,
            error: "cancelCheckout"
        });

        return null;
    }
    changePaymentMethodTapped?(): () => void {
        return null;
    }
    finishCheckout(): (result: PXResult) => void {
        this.resolve({
            status: "finishCheckout",
            data: null,
            error: null
        });

        return null;
    }
}

export class MercadopagoPx {
    public start(options: Options): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let checkout = MercadoPagoCheckout.alloc().initWithBuilder(
                MercadoPagoCheckoutBuilder.alloc()
                    .initWithPublicKeyPreferenceId(
                        options.publicKey,
                        options.preferenceId
                    )
                    .setLanguage(options.language)
            );

            let lifeCycleProtocolDelegate: LifeCycleProtocolImpl = LifeCycleProtocolImpl.new();
            lifeCycleProtocolDelegate.resolve = resolve;
            lifeCycleProtocolDelegate.reject = reject;

            let pxLifeCycleProtocol: PXLifeCycleProtocol = lifeCycleProtocolDelegate;

            checkout.startWithNavigationControllerLifeCycleProtocol(
                frameModule.topmost().ios.controller,
                pxLifeCycleProtocol
            );
        });
    }
}
```

My custion is how to access here, actually not access because i have wrong with linter TS :

```js
finishCheckout(): (result: PXResult) => void {
        console.dir(result); <---- Here error, can't access to result
        this.resolve({
            status: "finishCheckout",
            data: null,
            error: null
        });

        return null;
    }
```

Trying to access the object, I can not because it detects that the variable does not exist, when it is present, I do not know if it is the way to access the property, or if there is a way to access that object that returns the method to me which try to implement

Answer (score 0):

It means you are returning a function from `finishCheckout` which has a parameter `result`.

```
finishCheckout(): (result: PXResult) => void {
        console.dir(result); <---- Here error, can't access to result
        this.resolve({
            status: "finishCheckout",
            data: null,
            error: null
        });

        return null;
    }
```

It suppose to be,

```
finishCheckout(result: PXResult) {
    console.dir(result); 
    this.resolve({
        status: "finishCheckout",
        data: null,
        error: null
    });

    return null;
}
```

if `result` should be a parameter for `finishCheckout`.

**Edit:**

As per the typings (`finishCheckout(): (p1: PXResult) => void;`), the method doesn't have a parameter but it returns a function that will have result as a parameter. Hence you can't access result in there.

Comment: Thank you for your response but if I do what you tell me it makes me an error since the typings do not have defined the form that you put as a solution, would it be that I modify something else?

Comment: I'm not sure which library you are using, please link iOS documentation of your library I can take a look and let you know.

Comment: This library in github https://github.com/mercadopago/px-ios, and sdk http://mercadopago.github.io/px-ios/v4/, also me repo: https://github.com/NeriCodec/nativescript-mercadopago-px

Comment: One solution in objetive-c this - (void (^)(id<PXResult> _Nullable))finishCheckout {
  return ^ (id<PXResult> _Nullable result) {
    PXPayment *payment = (PXPayment *) result;
    NSLog(payment.description);
  };
}, but I don't know how to use it

Comment: How could I use the function with the result? (finishCheckout(): (p1: PXResult) => void;)